# Pyspark: Problems reading tables in a cluster with hdfs:\\ master:

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have initialized a spark session in this way:

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder \
                .appName('LSC_PROJECT') \
                .getOrCreate()
```

then i try to read much tables in this way:

```
df = self.spark_session.read.\
            csv(path=WAV.PATH_FILES_WAV+'/*.txt', header=False, schema= data_structure, sep='\t').\
            withColumn("Filename", reverse(split(input_file_name(), "/")).getItem(0) ).\
            withColumn("duration", col("End") - col("Start"))
```

The problem is that this work when I run it with spark in local, but when I run it on the cluster i obtain the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user24/LSCproject/Main.py", line 42, in <module>
    wav.recording_annotation()
  File "/home/user24/LSCproject/wav_manipulation/wav.py", line 45, in recording_annotation
    csv(path='LSCproject/Database/audio_and_txt_files/*.txt', header=False, schema= data_structure, sep='\t').\
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 441, in csv
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/user24/LSCproject/Database/audio_and_txt_files/*.txt;'
```

Any direction or recommendations are greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

*Output uning /user/user24/LSCproject/Database/ instead of WAV.PATH_FILES_WAV+'/*.txt*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user24/LSCproject/Main.py", line 42, in <module>
    wav.recording_annotation()
  File "/home/user24/LSCproject/wav_manipulation/wav.py", line 45, in recording_annotation
    csv(path='/user/user24/LSCproject/Database/', header=False, schema= data_structure, sep='\t').\
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 441, in csv
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/user24/LSCproject/Database;'
```

Comment: what is the value for this - path=WAV.PATH_FILES_WAV ?

Comment: In local I use a function that return the path where are located the .txt files. In local works well, but on  the cluster doesn't works. I tried to put also the entire path that is  hdfs://master:9000/user/user24/LSCproject/Database/*.txt

Comment: can you try only this with hdfs - /user/user24/LSCproject/Database/ & hdfs://master:9000/user/user24/LSCproject/Database/*.txt also post output here.

Comment: Yes, I updated the post with the results

Comment: what about hdfs command , hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://master:9000/user/user24/LSCproject/Database/*.txt, can you post this log after executing.

Comment: ls: `hdfs://master:9000/user/user24/LSCproject/Database/*.txt': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Exception message says HDFS Path does not exist, Add correct HDFS Path & try again.

```
Path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/user24/LSCproject/Database
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user24/LSCproject/Main.py", line 42, in <module>
    wav.recording_annotation()
  File "/home/user24/LSCproject/wav_manipulation/wav.py", line 45, in recording_annotation
    csv(path='/user/user24/LSCproject/Database/', header=False, schema= data_structure, sep='\t').\
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 441, in csv
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/user24/LSCproject/Database;'
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but the problem is that the path should be correct, i check it many times. How can get the hdfs path in a way similar to pwd command on the bash?

Comment: is it running in your local or cluster ?

Comment: can tell me where exactly files are available.. execute ls & show output

Comment: Sorry, the path of hdf was wrong,  i forgot the audio_and_txt_files folder, but i tried also with the correct path and doesn't works. Howevere executing pwd in the folder where the txt files are located I've got:  /home/user24/LSCproject/Database/audio_and_txt_files